# bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot error

Tags: windows, boot, virus

I cannot boot into my Windows version due to a virus, I was able to boot into another partitioned copy of Windows and access msconfig, which I then selected the virus ridden partitioned and checked "safeboot minimal" but DID NOT select "make change permanant". However now when I boot up it always boots to the Windows 8 partition with the virus, and doesn't even give me the option of selected a different partition (boot manager).
So I stuck in a Windows 7 installation disk and hit, Repair you computer, selected the virus'ed partition and opened up command prompt.
I tried:

```
bcdedit {default} /deletevalue safeboot
```

but no avail, and I'm not sure why. I get an error to do with '/?'

full output of bcdedit is below.
F:/ is the virus ridden im trying to remove safeboot from.

```
identifier {bootmgr}
device partition=C:
inherit {globasettings}
desc windows boot manager
bit and pieces irelevant
identifier {default}
device partition=F:
path \Windows\system32\winload.exe
desc windows 8
inherit {bootloadersettings}
recoveryenabled yes
osdevice partition=F:
systemroot \Windoiws
safeboot Minimal
safebootalternatshell No
```

so {default} safeboot is registered and bcdedit is found and runs ok.
what would be the command to remove the safeboot value as the above didnt work?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format of the command is a little different, the actual use would be:

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot
```

Answer (score 3):

`bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot` worked for me, despite every post online (including the other answer here) also specifies `{default}` to that command (which gives me an error every time).

Either it changed, or everyone's just repeating the same bad information without knowing what they're talking about. I started trying everything and that's what stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Success! I tried many listed approaches without initial success. I had to create a Windows 10 install usb drive. I set the bios to boot from the drive and restarted the laptop, chose repair on the second install screen to get to trouble shooting then advanced trouble shooting to get to the command prompt. What worked for me was changing the path. Starting at x:\Sources and typing cd: to get to X:\ then typing bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safe with success. Maybe this will work for someone else.
Windows 10 Home Edition

Comment: Borg, you must refer the link https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, will help you to recreate the answer.